# Centering the data in a cell in grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and i'm associating the datasource for the grid view dynamically at runtime

I mean

```
 gridView2.DataSource = titlesArrayList;
 gridView2.DataBind();
```

And i want the data in cells of this grid view to be centered, right now they are left-justified

If i was associating data through

```
<asp:BoundField />
```

I have this property

```
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
```

But how can i access this property if the gridview is associated dynamically

I hope u understand my problem

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT:

try

```
        foreach (GridViewRow  row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Attributes.CssStyle["text-align"] = "center";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I want to center align the content in each cell of my gridview that is being dynamically bound to datasource.

Comment: @user ItemStyle does exactly that.

Comment: but it is only center-aligning the items that I'm setting using ItemTemplate not for the columns that r being dynamically set by the datasource here is the link to my output http://postimage.org/image/1e8xlpb5w/ It is only centering the remove button which i'm setting using Itemtemplate not other columns which i'm setting using arraylist

Comment: thanks a lot!! It works perfectly. Thank you for the quick responses and taking your time. Have a nice day.

Comment: But it's way may cause "text-align" appear in every cell, to heavy the load of page.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably from the mark-up. Just assign `HorizontalAlign` to Center in the grid's `RowStyle`. No need to iterate through every cell programmatically.

**Example:**

```
<asp:GridView>
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<Columns>
...
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below style block before the GridView

```
<style>
    td, th {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```